# Authentication Failed- Google Internet Accounts

Tags: macos, mac, mojave, google

I am trying to add my google account but I am getting the error below. I am running Mojave and have tried several google accounts.

[image]

Comment: Same here. The timing of Google cleaning up their act and Google+ getting canned makes me think this is on Google's infrastructure end causing the issue. I haven't gotten their support to confirm yet.

Comment: @Doug, out of curiosity, do you have two factor auth turned on?

Comment: Same issue.  We can log in through a browser, and the problem is isolated to a single user account on a computer with multiple users.